# How to write HQL Query?

Tags: nhibernate, hql

My query is in SQL

```
Session.CreateQuery("SELECT MAX(T.Maximum) FROM (SELECT COUNT(ID) as 'Maximum' FROM Privilege WHERE IsActive = 1 GROUP BY PrivilegeModuleID ) AS T");
```

But i don't know the syntax in HQL (nhibernate)

if any one know please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't select from a subselect (implicit view) in HQL. But in your case this subselect isn't really needed, so the solution should be simple:

```
select max(count(p.ID)) from Privilege p where p.IsActive = 1 group by p.PrivilegeModule.id
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(P.PRIVILEGE_ID) FROM PRIVILEGE P WHERE IS_ACTIVE = 1  GROUP by P.PRIVILEGE_MODULE_ID ORDER BY COUNT(P.PRIVILEGE_ID) DESC